# Cannot found declaration for element "context:property-placeholder"

Tags: java, xml, spring

Im a Spring beginner. I browsed this and only got [this note](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/8500844/218454)

My two xml files:

one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="url">stackoverflow.com/</entry>
</properties>
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd"            
 >

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.xml" />

<security:authentication-manager>
  <security:ldap-server url="${url}" 
    manager-dn="XXX" manager-password="XXX" />
</beans>
```

I get the Exception is:

> Cannot found declaration for element "context:property-placeholder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for context schema namespace you didn't specify the schema location. change you beans declaration like this.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
```